# Regex Ignore text in square brackets

Tags: regex, uipath

I need help in creating this regex for replacing the text

Heres the sample input:

```
<variable class="loves">[loves] My dog loves dog food </variable>
```

Heres the sample output i am expecting:

```
<variable class="loves">[loves] My dog hates dog food </variable>
```

Thank you

The regex i am currently using highlights the word loves written in square brackets as well as outside the square bracket. I want to ignore the word loves written in square bracket

- I am using this regex - `(?<=variable.*>.*)loves(?=.*<\/variable)`

Comment: You can exclude the square brackets using negative lookarounds `(?<!\[)\bloves\b(?!])` The word boundaries will prevent a partial word match if you also want that. Note that in matching `<variable` would be a bit more specific, and also `.*` can cross matching `<` and `>` and may match more than you would expect.

Comment: Your output is identical to your input, is this intended?

Comment: Add another look-around, _(?<=variable.*>.*)(?<!\[)loves(?=.*<\/variable)_

Answer (score 0):

A most generic solution and rather a quick fix here would look like

```
(?<=<variable.*>.*)loves(?!(?<=\[[^][]*)[^][]*])(?=.*</variable)
```

The `(?!(?<=\[[^][]*)[^][]*])` negative lookahead placed right after `loves` makes it match only when the `loves` substring does not appear in between square brackets with no other square brackets in between.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zIxdUw/2)

Note that the multiple `.*` parts will make the regex search slower, and the `loves` part is matched even inside longer words (like `gloves`). To address the first problem, make use of negated character classes and to address the second one, use word boundaries:

```
(?<=<variable[^>]*>[^>]*)\bloves\b(?!(?<=\[[^][]*)[^][]*])(?=[^<]*</variable)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zIxdUw/3).

The `[^>]*` and `[^<]*` patterns won't work if you have other tags inside `variable` tag, so you will have to rely either on `.*` or a tempered greedy token like `(?:(?!</?variable\b).)*`.